# div в разных родителях в зависимости от ширины экрана/окна

Tags: jquery, css3

Нужно изменять положение блока div на странице в зависимости от ширины экрана/окна следующим образом:

1. на малых экранах (или в окнах, не развернутых на ширину, допустим, более 1024px) div размещаем/отображаем в родительском блоке article;
2. на больших экранах тот же div помещаем в блок aside.

Хотелось бы именно один div использовать в разных положениях, а не два, для одного из которых указывать display:none на определенных @media

Возможно ли это реализовать на jQuery?
Спасибо.

Comment: Видимо, следует  поместить в переменную html-код перемещаемого блока. И добавить в разметку два пустых div в нужных местах для десктопов (div class="desk") и мобилок (div class="mob"). А далее по условию ширины окна добавлять в нужный div методом append ту самую переменную с html-кодом. Завтра вечером попробую.

Comment: Ну, или innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае блок нужно поместить в aside, а в зависимости от размера экрана размещать его в разных местах. Это можно реализовать на css.

```
    <header><h1>Адаптивная верстка</h1></header>
    <div class="container">
      <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</article>
      <aside><div>Div в aside</div></aside>
    </div>
    <style>
      .container {
        display: flex;
      }
      @media all and (max-width: 480px) {
        .container {
          display: block;
        }
      }
    </style>
```

В данном случае если максимальная ширина 480px, то div разместится под article.

Comment: Спасибо. Адаптивной версткой я владею. У меня задача именно такова, какой я ее описала. Этот перемещаемый блок содержит форму с динамически добавляемыми полями (строками прайса), мне нужно, чтобы пользователь видел, что кликнутая им строка появилась в форме, которую он сейчас отправит. Если на малых экранах она будет в сдвинутом вниз блоке aside, юзер просто не будет видеть, что строка добавилась.

Comment: Вероятно, можно с помощью js прокрутить немного вниз